# Android Layout Image display in wrong position on a Table row

Tags: android, image, layout

I have an ImageView on the left and a Table on the right. Inside table there is one row display 2 images but the result is one image on left and the other image on the right. they are not adjacent?! Why ?

Any Hints ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="true" 
>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_Photo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/image_name"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/sample" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/HouseMall_Title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/HouseMall_Name_In_Chinese"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#0000FF"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/row2Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/row2_Title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/row2Fee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#EE0000"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/row3Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/row3_Title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/row3Fee"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#EE0000"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
           <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/indoor_or_outdoor"
             android:layout_width="30dp"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:scaleType="centerInside"
             android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
             android:contentDescription="@+id/indoor_outdoor_name"
             android:src="@drawable/indoor_18x18" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="2dp" 
             android:paddingRight="2dp" 
    />     
         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/promotion"
             android:layout_width="30dp"
             android:layout_height="20dp"
             android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:scaleType="centerInside"
             android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
             android:contentDescription="@+id/hasPromotion"
             android:src="@drawable/promotion_no_18x18" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="2dp" 
             android:paddingRight = "2dp"
    />                   

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: Also, move the android:layout_gravity  for the imageviews to the TableRow as android:gravity, you can also get rid of android:layout_gravity in the imageviews.

Answer (score 0):

Use in table row:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```